# How to indent numbered sections and subsections in R Markdown (bookdown)?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I know how to indent text such as bullets and numeric lists, but I am also interested in indenting numbered sections and subsections as well. Given the following code, it renders to the screen shot following the code. The table of contents has subsections indented and I would like to indent the content body as well.

Is there a way to indent the subsections in the body of the document as well? See the `Desired Output Example` item afterwards.

```
---
title: "R Markdown Example With Numbered Sections"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
  toc: true
toc_depth: 6
number_sections: true
---

# Section A

## Level 2 A

### Level 3 A

#### Level 4 A

## Level 2 A

# Section B

## Level 2 B
```

**Rendered without indented subsections**

[image]

**Desired Output Example**

```
... table of contents as above ...

1 Section A
  1.1 Level 2 A
    1.1.1 Level 3 A
      1.1.1.1 Level 4 A
  1.2 Level 2 A
2 Section B
  2.1 Level 2 B
```

**EDIT: 2021-12-15**

The solution for this by @Peter worked for me on the Mac but required a workaround for the Linux system I am using. I found the issue with the solution not working on my Linux machine was the result of a bug in version 2.10 of `titlesec` (which is what I have). The fix can be either to update `titlesec` or use a workaround; both are described in this link: [titlesec: loss of section numbering with the new update (2016/03/15)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299969/titlesec-loss-of-section-numbering-with-the-new-update-2016-03-15#:%7E:text=64-,Update,-The%20issue%20has)

Comment: You can try to use something like:

`
header-includes:
  - \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\hspace{1cm}\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}} 
`

Here, this is further discussed: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection

Comment: @Lucas Thanks. I need to better understand how to translate complete TeX solutions to R Markdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure if it is the heading in the table of contents (toc) or or the headings in the body of the document that want to be indented.

You can indent the headings in the text using the latex `titlesec` package and the `titlespacing` command (as originally posted, then deleted following comments from @manro).

However, this only works for the first three levels `out of the box`, which in latex-land are generally considered enough. Updated comment @manro has found a solution to this.

Indentation in the toc is more straight forward: its a case of getting the correct indentation for the yaml commands...

```
---
title: "R Markdown Example With Numbered Sections"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 6
number_sections: true

header-includes:
- \usepackage{titlesec}
---


\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*4}{*1.5}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{20pt}{*4}{*1.5}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{40pt}{*4}{*1.5}
\titlespacing{\subsubsubsection}{60pt}{*4}{*1.5} # does not work


# Section A


## Level 2 A

### Level 3 A

#### Level 4 A

## Level 2 A

# Section B

## Level 2 B
```

[image]

Comment: Author of question wants different output.

Comment: @manro OP states: " The table of contents has subsections indented and I would like to ~indent the content body~ as well." my italics, how do you interpret the question?

Comment: I don't understand him fully. But I know how to fix your answer a little ;)

Comment: @manro Do you think the OP wants the table of contents to display to level 4 (possibly level 6) with each level indented a bit more than the last? That could be an understanding of the question.

Comment: I think, yes...

Comment: this is a strange behaviour of bookdown, hmm.... "+1" ;) Where is Yihie :(

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity on the TOC. The `toc_depth: 6` was there for an example, and to some degree the TOC was already indenting (at least for `pdf_document`). The **main focus of this question** was to **get the body of the document to have indented subsections**. I typically avoid a large depth value but 6 was somewhere to start. Both of the answers from @Peter and @manro address this question. I messed up on the accepted answer and will change to @Peter for two reasons, it was the first answer solving the problem and it uses `bookdown::pdf_doucment2` which I am using.

Comment: @Peter The above answer works on when I run on the Mac, but on my Linux system the section numbers are missing just by adding `- \usepackage{titlesec}` to the `header-includes` section. I am not sure how to troubleshoot this but the versions of `bookdown` are the same.

Comment: @Peter FYI,  I found the issue with the solution not working on my Linux machine, it was the result of a bug in version **2.10** of `titlesec`. The fix can be either to update `titlesec` or use a workaround; both are described in this link: [titlesec: loss of section numbering with the new update (2016/03/15)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299969/titlesec-loss-of-section-numbering-with-the-new-update-2016-03-15#:~:text=64-,Update,-The%20issue%20has)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but in

```
bookdown::pdf_document2:
```

... `toc_depth` can be only `max = 2`.

**Maybe, it is a bug?** Or I did something wrong?

But, for

```
output: pdf_document
```

... we can make this solution (***Peter***, I remember your contribution!)

```
---
title: "Toc is Toc"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{titlesec}

output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex
    toc: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc_depth: 4
  
documentclass: article
---

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*4}{*1.5} 
\titlespacing{\subsection}{20pt}{*4}{*1.5}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{40pt}{*4}{*1.5} 
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{60pt}{*4}{*1.5}



\section{I don't know}
\subsection{Why}
\subsubsection{In bookdown}
\paragraph{TocDepth is only two}
```

[image]

**P.S.** [Mr. Yihui Xie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui-xie), can you shed light on this case? Thanks ;)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. The above solution using `titlesec` works for `bookdown::pdf_document2` as well, but as you mention, the indentation for `Contents` only goes to two levels. However, it does go to deeper levels in the body of the doc, which is what I am looking for. I started using `bookdown::pdf_document2` because it allows me to reference figures & tables by chunk reference, so I am hesitant to move away from `bookdown::pdf_document2`.

Comment: @steveb Yes, while you can work with this material. I hope, that Yihie tells to us something later about only two levels in the bookdown...